How to store a dynamic C string
For an assignment in my college data structures class, we have to define functions for a palindrome class that takes a word, checks if it is a palindrome, stores it as half the word, and can access certain aspects of it in C++.
I need to declare a string variable in the palindrome class with a dynamic size so that I can store words of different sizes.
I should note that all of this must be done from scratch, and I'm not allowed to use the string or cstring classes.
Is this possible? Or do I need a different approach?
Header file for the class:
class Palindrome{

   public:

      Palindrome();
      Palindrome(const char* str);
      Palindrome(const Palindrome& other);
      ~Palindrome();
      Palindrome& operator=(const Palindrome& other);

      void set_palindrome(const char* str);

      int length() const;
      int storage_size() const;
      char char_at(int pos) const;
      void set_char_at(char c, int pos);

      int compare(const Palindrome& other) const;
      int compare(const char* other) const;
      bool operator<(const Palindrome& other) const;
      bool operator<(const char* other) const;

      static bool isPalindrome(const char* str);

      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Palindrome& pal);
    private:
        int len;
        int store_size;
        
};

I tried to initialize a C string as a private data member, but it required me to specify a size for it. I'm not sure how to change the size of a C string, or if I just have to make a new one.

Nothing is preventing you from using std::string as a member is it?   As for Palindrome(const char* str);. Try not to use raw pointers in C++. use Palindrome(std::string_view str). That would be the correct C++ answer

You're taking a const char* in one of your constructors.  Why not use a member variable of the same type if you can't use std::string?

However if you are not allowed to use the standard library it would be a good thing to tell us that in your question.

You must surely be allowed to study existing algorithms. If you are, the example usage of std::equal may provide som inspiration

"I'm not allowed to use the string or cstring classes." -- Does this prevent you from writing a LeafMan::string class? (Just implement the parts you need for now, and build upon it for your next assignment.)

One (pretty bad) way to handle C strings as members is to know that it will never be larger than - say - 100 characters, and have space for that.

@BoP Leaning hard on std::realloc would be an option.

"I tried to initialize a c string as a private data member but it required me to specify a size for it." -- This part is not clear, because there is no single "C string" type (and because this data member is not in your sample code). Multiple types can be used to store C-style strings, although they can be summarized as char* and char[N] (with N ranging, hence more than just two types).

Did you write the header, or was it provided to you?  Do you know the pedagogical goal of the assignment (what you're supposed to learn to do)?

"I should note that all of this must be done from scratch, and I'm not allowed to use the string or cstring classes." -- Should I infer from this that you are also not allowed to use std::unique_ptr<char[]>? (Is memory management part of the assignment?)

@Ted - I'm more into How long is the longest one word palindrome, and it turns out to be 19 characters (and only if you know Finnish). So a dynamic string is kind of an overkill here.

@BoP :-D That's brillant! With such knowledge, there are optimizations one can make. I didn't know "saippuakivikauppias" before (which is the much simpler "täljstenshandlare" in my native language) - but I will try to remember it!

You're in luck!  The std::string class is a dynamic text variable, that will expand as necessary.  You'll have manually contract the size if you want to shrink it later.  The std::string has a method c_str() and data which can be used with C-Style NUL terminated character arrays.

If the point of this is to teach you how to implement dynamically allocated strings, then I would decouple that from the palindrome stuff. First, code class Palindrome using std::string. Then, as was suggested by @JaMiT (above), write your own lightweight String class, that only implements the parts of std::string that are used in class Palindrome. Don't forget the Rule of Three functions. Finally, in class Palindrome, replace std::string with String.

Given the constraints you've been given, your best options would be to use a std::unique_ptr<char[]>.
While something like std::vector<char> would handle resizing for you, it isn't so nice if you have to maintain null termination of the string, and in this case, it doesn't appear you have to append or resize the string.
So, what I would recommend is using a std::unique_ptr<char[]>, which you can allocate with std::make_unique<char[]>(length), and then do a string copy via a handful of methods. The unique_ptr will handle deallocation of the memory. The main thing you have to worry about is null termination, if that's needed.

The "must be done from scratch" requirement suggests that neither std::unique_ptr nor std::vector would be allowed, even though they were not explicitly mentioned in the question. Which would make sense if one point of the exercise is to implement memory management.

I disagree with the other answers.
The purpose of your assignment is to write a class that properly encapsulates new[] and delete[] for an array of dynamically-allocated data.
Make sure to obey the Rule of Three/Five/Zero.
To answer the the question-in-a-question: yes, to resize your string, you must:

allocate a new array and, if successful,
copy the content of the old array to the new one,
add the new content (if the array is increased in size),
delete the old array,
update the object to reference the new array


My best guess—and it is only a guess—is that you are right. This assignment is about rolling your own String class. If that is right, would you decouple class Palindrome from class String as was suggested in comments by @JaMiT and me, or would you put it all in class Palindrome?

@tbxfreeware If I were writing a general-purpose string class, it would totally be decoupled. If I were writing a special-purpose class that does special stuff with palindromes, then I’d maybe consider making it part of the specialized class... but there had better be really good reasons. For a homework assignment, IDK if it matters...

You don't need to use string, you could use std::vector for storage.
It looks like the string is being provided as a C-style string (e.g const char*). So in the constructor check if it's a palindrome, if it's not then throw an exception (this is the only way to "fail" construction).
If it is a palindrome you can store it in a std::vector or std::list.
If your professor really doesn't want you using standard library then you're going to have to use new.. but at this point you're intentionally writing less-safe code (standard library containers handle the lifetime management of memory for you while using new and delete means you are more prone to memory leaks)

Since the task involves "to store a dynamic c string" you may want to touch upon that a bit. "So in the constructor check if it's a palindrome" - ... is that an attempt at an answer? If you are using generative AI, you are doing it wrong.

"but at this point you're intentionally writing less-safe code" -- Not necessarily. It is possible to replicate everything the standard library does in your own classes. That is, write your own version of unique_ptr to localize the use of new and delete.
